# Can anybody explain this question to me

Tags: discussion, specific-question, fun

I just came across this question [Join two spheres with a cylinder in WPF 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257964) and a [handful of others](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/873) and am wondering

How did this happen? and ... what is with the long detailed answer?

Comment: Lance Roberts just rolled back the question to the previous edit while I was trying to roll it back. :)  Needless to say, I concur with his decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that he accidentally deleted it when trying to change tags.  I just rolled it back.

I fixed 2 of the others, they were posted in html, so I just backquoted them, now they show.

Comment: Nice work on those other questions too. Looks like the Markup editor was just sanitizing input.

Comment: is this a bug somewhere, id assume a machine could detect this